# How many six digit numbers are even or are divisible by 5?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, inclusion-exclusion

Here is my attempt:

$$\text{Let A be the set of 6-digit numbers that are even.}$$
$$\text{Let B be the set of 6-digit numbers divisible by 5.}$$
$$\text{Thus, $A\cap B$ is the set of 6-digit numbers that are even and divisible by 5.}$$
$$|A|=9\cdot 10^4\cdot 5,\space|B|=9\cdot 10^4\cdot 2$$
$$\implies |A\cup B|=9\cdot 10^4+9\cdot 10^4\cdot 5-|A\cap B| $$

I must use the Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion but I'm having difficulty finding $A\cap B$. I only know I have 2 choices (0 or 5) for the ones digit since it must be divisible by 5.

Comment: Hint: $A\cap B$ is the set of all six-digit numbers which are divisible by $10$.

Comment: Does that mean I only have 0 as a choice for the ones digit?

Comment: Yes, it does. BTW, your value for $|B|$ is not quite right, but I assume that is a typing or copying error.

Comment: Edited. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: I don't quite understand how to reach the conclusion that six-digit numbers that are even and are divisible by 5 are just six-digit numbers that are divisible by 10.

Comment: If its even, it divides by 2. So it's divisible by both 5 and 2...

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, thank you.

Comment: Is the question "and" or "or"? The title says or, but the body indicates and...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number is even **or** a multiple of 5 exactly when it's final digit is one of $\{0,2,4,5,6,8\}$. There are $9$ possible choices for the first digit, $10$ choices for digits 2 to 5, and $6$ choices for the final digit, making a total of $9 \times 10^4 \times 6 = 540,000$ such numbers.

If you want to use the principle of inclusion-exclusion, observe that a number is even exactly when it ends in one of $\{0,2,4,6,8\}$, and is divisible by 5 exactly when the final digit is one of $\{0,5\}$. So, if a number is both even and divisible by 5, it must end in $0$, as the only number in both lists.

You have calculated $|A|$ and $|B|$ correctly, hopefully it is now clear that $|A \cap B|$ is just $9 \times 10^4$, and the final answer can be obtained with the inclusion-exclusion formula as you had in your question: $$9 \times 10^4 \times 5 + 9 \times 10^4 \times 2 - 9 \times 10^4 = 9 \times 10^4 \times 6 = 540,000.$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach.

Construe the problem as a probability problem.

The number of elements in the set

$$\{100000, 100001, \cdots, 999999\}$$

is $~999999 - 99999 = 900000.$

Since the digits $~\{0,1,\cdots, 9\}~$ are (in effect) each **equally likely** to occur in the rightmost place of the $~6~$ digit number, and since the constraints will be satisfied if and only if the rightmost digit is an element of $~\{0,2,4,5,6,8\},~$ rather than an element of $~\{1,3,7,9\},~$  you may **infer** that the probability of a random $~6~$ digit number having the appropriate rightmost digit is $~\dfrac{6}{10}.$

Therefore, the number of satisfying 6 digit numbers must be

$$900000 \times \frac{6}{10}.$$

Comment: simple, clear and elegant $+1$